# Android: Stopwatch application crashes due to CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android, stopwatch, thread-sleep

Here's my code for a stopwatch application on Android:

```
package com.google.labyrinth;

public class Tabalicious extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Runnable
{
    TextView    stopwatchCounter;

    long        startTime, stopTime;

    Thread      stopwatch;
    Button      buttonStart;
    Button      buttonStop;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.tabalicious );


        stopwatchCounter    = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.txtStopwatchCounter );
        buttonStart         = ( Button ) findViewById ( R.id.buttonStart );
        buttonStop          = ( Button ) findViewById ( R.id.buttonStop );

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener( this );

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener( this );
        buttonStop.setEnabled(false);

    }

    public void onClick(View viewClicked)
    {

        switch( viewClicked.getId() )
        {
        case R.id.buttonStart:

            this.buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            this.buttonStop.setEnabled(true);

            this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            stopwatch = new Thread(this);
            stopwatch.start();

            break;

        case R.id.buttonStop:

                this.buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                this.buttonStart.setEnabled(true);

            try {
                stopwatch.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;


        }

    }

    public void run()
    {
                    //Update after 5 seconds.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.stopwatchCounter.setText( String.valueOf( (this.stopTime - this.startTime) ) ); //<- Debugger Info: This line is at the top of the call stack.
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I run the application I get a CalledFromWrongThread exception:

> 02-10 19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-10 02-10 19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   02-10 19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3092) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:677) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:703)
>   02-10 19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2597) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5326) 02-10 19:53:32.835:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5761) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2814) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2682) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):
>
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2657) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):     at
>   com.google.labyrinth.Tabalicious.run(Tabalicious.java:144) 02-10
>   19:53:32.835: E/AndroidRuntime(18482):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)

I'm not quite clear on what's going on. I would appreciate your help. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to edit UI elements but you are not on the UI thread. In Android, UI elements can only be edited by the UI thread. There are many ways to update UI elements after doing computation on another thread, including calling the runOnUiThread() method, using a Handler, or overriding the PostExecute() method of an AsyncTask.

Comment: OK so instead of creating a thread, I called this.runOnUIThread(this), where the run method was as follows:
`public void run(){ while(isRunning){this.stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();Tabalicious.this.stopwatchCounter.setText( String.valueOf( (Tabalicious.this.stopTime - Tabalicious.this.startTime) ) );}}`

and my applicaiton fails to respond. Would it be better to only run the setText() method on the UI Thread or is it something else that I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @W.K.S The UIThread in Android handles all screen drawing and input events. So when you have put an while(isRunning) loop on it, you are blocking all the UI events since it is constantly running your loop. This is why you are having a not responding error. You should not run any computation on the UIThread, simply update the view when necessary. Keep the timer in a seperate thread, and only call runOnUiThread for when you are updating the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

this is only because you do :

this.stopwatchCounter.setText( String.valueOf( (this.stopTime - this.startTime) ) );

inside stopwatch thread, you can't touch the view because it isn't the UIThread.